# NSTimer in multitasking App

Tags: nstimer

In my app, i have a tab which runs NSTimer for recording time for each row of the table for some activity but as soon as i change the tab the timer of that screen reset. IS there any way that i can make my timer to run as long as application remains.

Comment: Is this an iOS or Mac OS app?

Comment: Make the timer run in your appdelegate instead of a view controller.